# Programmatically Run MYSQL workbench schema script in VB.NET Application

Tags: mysql, vb.net, schema, setup-deployment

Is there a code for running a MYSQL workbench schema script on another machine via VB.NET Application? so you know, to build a new schem on another machine, really having a hard time deploying my application with database,

thanks in advance for those who can answer